# Custom content for Wordpress site depending on visitor location

Tags: wordpress, location

I built a Wordpress website for my client.

As the next step my client would like to have his website display different phone numbers and customize content on some of the pages depending on the location of the site's visitor.

For example,  if the site's visitor is in Los Angeles, then the contact phone number would be (323)xxx-xxxx , but if the visitor is in Beverly Hills - the phone number would change to something like (310)-yyy-yyyy.

Similarly for the content of the pages: he'd like to customize website's copy to a location of the visitor. So in the above example the words "Los Angeles" would need to be replaced everwhere throughout the site with "Beverly Hills" in case the user is accessing the site from Beverly Hills.

I Googled around, but didn't see how to accomplish this most efficiently.

Thanks in advance for your time in assisting with my question.

Comment: you might want to post this to the WordPress Stack: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CMF solution is theoretically correct but very hard to implement in reality .
IT is not because of the solution itself - but because the resolution you require (it is not a country, nor state - you want "neighborhood" ) is too high . there is no guarantee that a user from Beverly hills will use a Beverly hills IP. I would also suggest using google geolocation to reverse the IP to address - but still - it is very likely to produce wrong results at times . My suggestion to you is to just list all the numbers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Location can be determine from visitor's IP address, you're good to go if you have a IP location database. To implement that on WordPress you should make some PHP function and put it on your WordPress template. Say if the thing you want to add is in the header, edit your header.php template to include the PHP function/code you've written.

Making this throughout the website could be more complicated, but I believe and sure that it can be done through filters and many other way. for the page content (posts/page) you can use 'the_content' filter. A brief example:

On your function.php template, add something like:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content' );
function filter_the_content( $content ) {
    if ( $location == 'Beverly Hills' )
    str_replace( 'Los Angeles', 'Beverly Hills', $content );

    return $content;
}
```

That is just an example and it will not work if you use above example.

The other way around, is using 'shortcode'. You can simply add a shortcode like `[location]`. Add create a function to replace the shortcode to show the location.

That was just a brief description of what you can do with WordPress. Be sure to check out the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/